# Launch Orange3 core dump for any >3.17

Tags: orange

Updated to 3.19 using Anaconda navigator, from CLI I receive these messages

```
orange-canvas
realloc(): invalid old size
Aborted (core dumped)

python3 -m Orange.canvas
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Using Anaconda navigator got this log

```
/home/davide445/.anaconda/navigator/scripts/orange3.sh: line 3:  8261 Aborted                 (core dumped) orange-canvas > /home/davide445/.anaconda/navigator/scripts/orange3-out-1.txt 2> /home/davide445/.anaconda/navigator/scripts/orange3-err-1.txt
```

Same problem with 3.20.1 or 3.18, is working using 3.17. Working on Kubuntu 18.04 LTS.
Any suggestion for troubleshooting, many thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem as you, and I just used pip to reinstall the 3.17 version.

```
pip install Orange3==3.17
```

Comment: Ok but did you find a way to use any version greater than 3.17?

Comment: @davide445 I have two computers. One is ubuntu and another is windows 10. It seems like only ubuntu has this problem because Orange's version on my windows 10 computer is 3.20.1 and it works well.